# Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Conflict with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

Login with facebook button throws an error. I'm using PHP SDK. I found there's some issue with `jquery-1.7.2.min.js`. Because when I remove jQuery from page it works just fine.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to include some code and the exact errors, or a link to the page, for someone to help.